# Parse error in pattern in haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

When implementing the DFS algorithm, I got to use the Imperative features. Here is the code

```
type ST s a = s -> (a, s)

returnST :: a -> ST s a
returnST a s = (a, s)

thenST :: ST s a -> (a -> ST s b) -> ST s b
(m 'thenST' k) s = k a t where (a, t) = m s
```

But the GHCi 6.12.3 give me a 'Parse error in pattern' in the last line of code. I get this piece of code from an paper. Is there any possibility that the complier used by the author of the paper got no strict grammar rules as now? And how to fix this error?

Comment: You know that DFS doesn't require mutable state, right?  Your first sentence implies otherwise.

Comment: @TomMD I just read a paper and want to implement his idea.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
'thenST'
```

to

```
`thenST`
```

The backticks turn an ordinary function name into an infix operator. They may have been turned into single quotes by an editor, word processor or document viewer.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. In my code, it's `thenST`. So the problem has nothing related with backticks

Comment: @machinarium: then I can't help you any further. GHCi 6.12.1 loads the code you posted just fine when I insert backticks.